# How to mock useeffect with props.childern.children

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How to mock useeffect with props.childern.children

```
function App({ loading, ...props }) {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (props.programs.length === 0) {
      props.loadPrograms();
    }

    if (props.exceptionTypes.length === 0) {
      props.loadExceptionTypes();
    }
}
```

Comment: *Don't* mock useEffect, that's part of the React API and you don't own it.

Comment: this part showing uncovered when checking jest coverage..then how can I create jest testcase for it or how will I cover that part?

Comment: It's hard to say because we can't see either what that code does or how you're currently testing it. I guess in general I'd suggest rendering `App` with appropriate values for the array props and test doubles (e.g. `jest.fn()`) of the callback props and see if the right things get called.